# Django-rules replacement of guardian.mixins.PermissionListMixin

Tags: django, guardian, django-rules

In my django based application I want to enable users to keep track of their locations. Each location has an owner, and the list view should only show the locations the current user owns.

With [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) I was able to achieve the same with specifying the following in my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from guardian.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin, PermissionListMixin

# Create your views here.
from .models import Location


class LocationListView(PermissionListMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Location
    permission_required = 'view_location'
    paginate_by = 20
    ordering = ['name']
```

How would I create something similar with [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to share Location model so we can advise you properly,  in both cases you need to specify queryset either in listview variable or by override get queryset method..

I would suggest you following lines of code assuming location model has foreign key from Auth User model where each location assigned to its owner..

```
  def get queryset(self):
    qs = Location.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
     return qs
```

Comment: I followed your lines of code (expect get_queryset() instead of get queryset()), and it worked as expected.

Comment: I just wonder how it would work with groups, but this would be a different question. :-) Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome,, andvthans for upvote!!